# Wordpress no muestra Achive-custom-post.php

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un custom post type llamado 'our-clients'. Cree un documento 'archive-our-clients.php' y cuando coloco en la URL 'http://localhost/wordpress/our-clients/' me muestra el index.

plugin

```
function our_clients(){
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Our Clients',
    'singular_name' => 'Our Client'
    );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'thumbnail',
      'editor',
      'revisions'),
    'menu_position' => 4,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_name' => 'Our Clients',
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled',
    'can_export' => true
    );
  register_post_type('our-clients', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'our_clients');
```

archive-our-clients.php

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'our-clients',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            ?>

            <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2> 

            <?php

            }

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Tengo entendido que los [custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) no son para acceder a ellos directamente, sino que los creas para **tener la posibilidad de crear posts de ese tipo**. Es decir, una especie de plantilla personalizada. ¿Cuál es el sentido de querer acceder a él directamente por url? En cuanto a que te manda al index, es posible que haya una regla en `.htaccess` que indique que todos los archivos con extensión `.php` sean redirigidos a `index.php`

Comment: Claro, pero es que lo que quiero es tener una pagina donde muestre el titulo, thumbnail y url que lleve a cada custom post que cree. Yo lo he hecho con anterioridad usando archive seguido con el nombre del custom post type, pero esta vez no me esta funcionado

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer. En teoría se trataría de poner esos elementos en el custom post type y cada post que crees del tipo `our-clients` presentará esos elementos como están en la plantilla. O sea, ¿piensas tener varios posts del tipo `our-clients` o lo que quieres es una página llamada `our-clients` que muestre cierto tipo de contenido? Si es el segundo caso  puedes crear un hook o un shortcode que llames desde la página `our-clients`y que te muestre lo que quieres. No termino de entender del todo lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Tengo el custom post type `our-clients` y quiero crear un template para cuando la url sea localhost/wordpress/our-clients (que es con `archive-our-clients.php`) y para cuando estas en la pagina de un cliente especifico, ejemplo: localhost/wordpress/our-clients/windows (que seria con `single-our-clients.php`). Mi problema es que ya tengo ambos archivos creados y al colocar las URL que te indiqué me muestra el template del index

Comment: De consejo también se debe renombrar bien los nombres de los CPT , por ejemplo esta mal llamarlos our-clients , debe ser our_clients , en la documentación se aconseja que debe hacer bien el rewrite : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types en el apartado URLs of Namespaced Custom Post Types Identifiers , por tema de los plurales.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te falta es usar `flush_rewrite_rules()`, así

```
function my_rewrite_flush() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

Fíjate en [este ejemplo](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation). Otra cosa que puedes hacer es intentar ir a **Ajustes > Enlaces Permanentes** y allí enviar el formulario nuevamente.